# I can't get id or data-test in cypress recently

Tags: npm, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to get a button with `[data-test=ex_button]` and click on it in cypress with using the following code:

```
cy.get('[data-test=ex_button]').click({ force: true })
```

and my UI code:

```
<el-button
  data-test="ex_button"
  type="primary"
  class="button-flat pull-right"
  @click="myFunction">
  {{ tr('myButtonName') }}
</el-button>
```

---

But Cypress fails with the following error message:

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: [data-test=ex_button], but never found it.
```

and when i want to open selector playground `cy.get()` for check it i never found it.

Comment: Can you use the locator `[data-test="ex_button"]` instead of `[data-test=ex_button]`.

Comment: @AlapanDas it's not my problem because i can't find data-test in ```open selector playground```

Comment: So when you use the selector tool and inspect the element, what do you get. Can you please post it here? OR the element is itself not visible on the cypress browser window ?

Comment: I had a similar issue with react-storybook, try to navigate to the parent element before doing a cy.get, for example, if your data-test is in an iframe or is in a hidden container, you would need to open/show it and it should be accessible using `tab` focus.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `data-test-id` attribute instead

Comment: For what reason? There is nothing special about that particular attribute name.